# Oracle SQL developer debugging index table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a bug in SQL developer, or limitation

I'm trying to see values in index table fields, but it shows me only 20 fields???

here is my example code below I'm looping 30 time, but in debug screen shows only 20.

Does anyone know how I can see all fields?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST AS 
   TYPE Fieldvalue IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (100)
                         INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   Field_Position        Fieldvalue;
BEGIN
  for i in 1..30 loop
        Field_Position(i) := 'hello ' || i;
    end loop;
      dbms_output.put_line('hello');
END TEST;
```

I put debug break point on  dbms_output.put_line('hello');  and it show only 20 records?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug in Oracle SQL Developer.  It works fine in other IDEs.  I'd recommend posting this in the [SQL Developer forums](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/sql_developer).

Answer (score 0):

Without using the debug screen on sql developer, you can just loop through the array (field_position) to see its content.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST AS 
   TYPE Fieldvalue IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (100)
                         INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
Field_Position        Fieldvalue;
BEGIN
for i in 1..30 loop
    Field_Position(i) := 'hello ' || i;
END loop;

FOR A IN FIELD_POSITION.FIRST..FIELD_POSITION.LAST
LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FIELD_POSITION(A));
END LOOP;

END TEST;
```

/

```
BEGIN
TEST;
END;
```